# How to cross join two arrays into one?

Tags: arrays, rxjs

For two arrays that have the same length, what operators are used to cross join them?

```
name = ['tom', 'jerry', 'pete'];
age = [4, 5, 6];
```

How to cross join them using RxJS, to get:

```
character = ['tom4', 'jerry5', 'pete6'];
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure this is an `rxjs` question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `name` and `age` are `observable` of an array, you can use the `.zip` operator:

```
Observable.zip(name,age,([named,aged])=>`{named}{aged}`)
```

If you want the results to be in an array, you can further `reduce` it:

```
Observable.zip(name, age, ([named, aged]) => `{named}{aged}`)
    .reduce((acc, x) => {
        return acc.push(x)
    }, [])
```

Comment: Right. I did not get the zip result because I used "of" instead of "from". Change it to "from" to get the sequence of stream.

Comment: BTW, don't need do reduce to convert to array. Just call .toArray().

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this is quite simple using from:

```
zip(from(name), from(age), (n: string, a: number) => 
    (n + String(a)))
.subscribe(val => console.log('zip output: ' + val));
```